# Snowflake - Store a part of a query in a variable or UDF

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a big where clause which I need to use it in Multiple views. So rather than writing this where clause at multiple places, I am thinking I can save this whole bit in a variable or a UDF function or Somewhere. Once done, all I need to do is call that Variable/UDF on the view. Basically reducing the boilerplate code.

For Example

```
Where
'_ALL' in 
(select distinct col1 from tablename
where ID = CURRENT_USER())
or
COLNAME in 
(select distinct col1 from tablename
where ID = CURRENT_USER())
)
```

This is just 1 condition that I have added here, I have 10 such columns on which I have to write the similar condition. And I need to use this same piece of code at 20 different places.

So the output I am looking at is:

```
where $variable
     or 
where UDF()
```

How can I make it look a little less complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use UDFs that way. What may work if all the views are referring to the same base table(s) is creating those views off a view with the initial where clause. Something like this:

```
create or replace view base_view as 
select * from base_table
Where
'_ALL' in 
(select distinct col1 from tablename
where ID = CURRENT_USER())
or
COLNAME in 
(select distinct col1 from tablename
where ID = CURRENT_USER())
)
```

Then you can create views on top of this base view:

```
create or replace view new_view
as
select * from base_view where ....
```

Comment: Nop.. This wont work for me, I tried doing this.. So the problem is 'COLNAME' in the query you shared is not present in 'tablename', so the base view will not get created.!

Comment: Is "tablename" the same or does it change too? If it's always the same, a UDTF would work and I can provide an example.

Comment: Always the same. Everything in the where clause section will exactly be as is..

Comment: Can you help me with the UDTF example. I still haven't found a way out to find a solution for this.

Comment: If I understand the requirement properly, the "tablename" could change. I have not been able to get that to work in a UDTF. JavaScript UDTFs don't have the "snowflake" SQL API. SQL UDTFs obviously can run SQL, but I cannot get it to dynamically change "tablename". If that's not what you need and tablename is the same every time, I can send that.

Comment: Again, as per my requirement, Tablename will not change.